# ACF repeater fields overwriting rather than updating

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an API where I pull in portfolio images for models from a portal via php into a custom post type in Wordpress. It pulls in the first image and then I manually upload some more in Wordpress like so..

[image]

However when I fetch the API again it overwrites the entire portfolio instead of updating it!!!

Here is the code..

```
    private function set_talent_contents($talent, $post_id)
{

    $terms = $talent['www'];
    $gender = $talent['gender'];

    if($this->actions['full_content'] && $talent['pic_1'] && $talent['pic_1'] != 'http://portal.pha-agency.co.uk/models/' )
    {

        $attachments = $this->uploadRemoteImageAndAttach($talent['pic_1'], $post_id);

        $pictures[] = [ 'image' => $attachments ];



        if( $this->actions['feature'] )
        {
            $output['feature'] = '&#10003;';

            set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachments );
        }


    }else{
        $pictures = null;
    }




    $headshot = (isset($pictures[0]['image']) ? $pictures[0]['image'] : null);

    $videos = [];

    $polaroids = [];



    if($this->actions['full_content'])
    {

        update_field($this->field_mapping['default']['headshot'], $headshot, $post_id);
        update_field($this->field_mapping['default']['portfolio'], $pictures, $post_id);
        update_field($this->field_mapping['default']['videos'], $videos, $post_id);
        update_field($this->field_mapping['default']['polaroids'], $polaroids, $post_id);
    }

    update_field($this->field_mapping['default']['header'], $this->field_mapping['default']['header_default'], $post_id);



    $talent_cats = array_filter(explode(',', $terms));

    if($talent_cats)
    {
        foreach($talent_cats as $cat)
        {
            $form_type = '';

            // just incase its something like 'Male Model'. we can strip the gender off and try the gender seperatly
            $cat = strtolower(trim(str_replace($gender, '', $cat)));

            if(isset($this->field_mapping[$cat]))
            {
               $form_type = $cat;

            }elseif(str_contains($cat, 'Sports') ){
                $form_type = 'sports';

            }elseif(str_contains($cat, 'model') || str_contains($cat, 'kids')){
                $form_type = 'models';

            }elseif(str_contains($cat, 'actor')){

                $form_type = 'casting';
            }else{
                continue;
            }


            if($this->actions['full_content'])
            {
                update_field($this->field_mapping[$form_type]['header'], $this->field_mapping[$form_type]['header_default'], $post_id);

                update_field($this->field_mapping[$form_type]['headshot'], $headshot, $post_id);
                update_field($this->field_mapping[$form_type]['portfolio'], $pictures, $post_id);
                update_field($this->field_mapping[$form_type]['videos'], $videos, $post_id);
                update_field($this->field_mapping[$form_type]['polaroids'], $polaroids, $post_id);
            }





        }
    }
```

Now, I have inherited this code and need to make it work properly. I have got in touch with ACF to see if it is a bug in the repeater field and this was the response:

```
    // save a repeater field value
   $field_key = "field_12345678";
   $value = array(
    array(
        "sub_field_1"   => "Foo",
        "sub_field_2"   => "Bar"
    )
   );
   update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
```

Now I'm just not sure how to implement it!